# Trying to use standalone mode

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I use this in standalone mode?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\bigstrutjot = 1ex \captionsetup{labelsep = none, skip=0pt} 
\renewcommand{\theBAenumi}{\Alph{BAenumi}}
    \[ \mathbf{\widehat R }= \begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{black}}c}}
    & \scriptstyle A & \scriptstyle B & \scriptstyle C & \scriptstyle D & \scriptstyle E \\
    \noalign{\setcounter{BAenumi}{1}}
    \begin{block}{>{\scriptstyle\theBAenumi}r!{\,}[ccccc]}
    & 5 & 3.09 & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.62}\bigstrut[t] \\
    & - & 2.89 & 4.69 & \mathbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \mathbf{2.78} & 3.71 \\
    & - & \mathbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29 & 2.22 \\
    & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.79} & 3.58 & 4.51 \\
    & \mathbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56 & 4.48 \\
    & 3.15 & \mathbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & - \\
    & 4.84 & \mathbf{2.92} & 4.72 & - & 4.61 \\
    & \mathbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & - \\
    & \mathbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29 & 4.22 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]%
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot use floats (like `figure`) in a standalone document easily. Why do you need the `figure` environment in a standalone document?

Comment: I actually do not need it but it does not work either when I remove `figure`

Comment: It throws `\mathbf allowed only in math mode. \[ \mathbf{ R }`

Comment: Equations do not work either. You can make it work by adding `\begin{minipage}{9cm}` after `\begin{document}` and `\end{minipage}` before `\end{document}`. Alternatively you can just use a `$\displaystyle ...$` equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can make it work. You can use a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\bigstrutjot = 1ex %\captionsetup{labelsep = none, skip=0pt} 
\renewcommand{\theBAenumi}{\Alph{BAenumi}}
    \[ \mathbf{\widehat R }= \begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{black}}c}}
    & \scriptstyle A & \scriptstyle B & \scriptstyle C & \scriptstyle D & \scriptstyle E \\
    \noalign{\setcounter{BAenumi}{1}}
    \begin{block}{>{\scriptstyle\theBAenumi}r!{\,}[ccccc]}
    & 5 & 3.09 & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.62}\bigstrut[t] \\
    & - & 2.89 & 4.69 & \mathbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \mathbf{2.78} & 3.71 \\
    & - & \mathbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29 & 2.22 \\
    & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.79} & 3.58 & 4.51 \\
    & \mathbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56 & 4.48 \\
    & 3.15 & \mathbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & - \\
    & 4.84 & \mathbf{2.92} & 4.72 & - & 4.61 \\
    & \mathbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & - \\
    & \mathbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29 & 4.22 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]%
 \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The downside is that you need to guess and hard code the width.

Alternatively you can just use an ordinary inline equation with `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\bigstrutjot = 1ex
\renewcommand{\theBAenumi}{\Alph{BAenumi}}
   \mathbf{\widehat R }= \begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{black}}c}}
    & \scriptstyle A & \scriptstyle B & \scriptstyle C & \scriptstyle D & \scriptstyle E \\
    \noalign{\setcounter{BAenumi}{1}}
    \begin{block}{>{\scriptstyle\theBAenumi}r!{\,}[ccccc]}
    & 5 & 3.09 & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.62}\bigstrut[t] \\
    & - & 2.89 & 4.69 & \mathbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \mathbf{2.78} & 3.71 \\
    & - & \mathbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29 & 2.22 \\
    & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.79} & 3.58 & 4.51 \\
    & \mathbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56 & 4.48 \\
    & 3.15 & \mathbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & - \\
    & 4.84 & \mathbf{2.92} & 4.72 & - & 4.61 \\
    & \mathbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & - \\
    & \mathbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29 & 4.22 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not require guesswork, nor hardcoding.